# Less: ---modify-var writes "undefined" into my CSS file

Tags: less

My CSS output contains the word "undefined" when I use --modify-var on the Less command line. Does anybody know why, and how to resolve?

My styles.css contains only:

```
@my-background: blue;
body{background: @my-background;}
```

My command line entry is:

```
lessc styles.less --modify-var=my-background:red
```

(Copied from here: http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-modify-variable)
(NB: I had to remove the quotes from their example because it gave a parsing error)

The output is:

```
body {
    background: red: undefined;
}
```

I'm using Lessc 1.6.3.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Ok, I found what is the actual problem . It's just a typo in the docs the correct syntax is: `--modify-var="my-background=red"`.

Comment: It worked! I replaced the colon with an equals sign and its all good. Thanks.